# Is there a way to export a DisplayObject's vector data?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, vector, displayobject

Flex gives the ability to export a display object as a bitmap as follows:

```
var bitmapDataBuffer:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( displayObject.width, displayObject.height, false);            
bitmapDataBuffer.draw ( displayObject, displayObject.transform.matrix);
```

Is there a method to export a display object as a vector graphic instead of bitmap data?

Answer (score 1):

The [`copyFrom()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Graphics.html#copyFrom()) function on the `Graphics` object might be what you need. It was added in Flash Player 10.

Comment: That's a cool method!  It still doesn't help me do what I need to do, since it transfers between graphics opjects and doesn't allow you to export that data into a format non graphics objects can understand (like svg or some other standard vector format).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the svgeditor-as3 library, however it uses it's own drawer engine, but it's very powerful, and can export in SVG format.

You can find more here:
http://code.google.com/p/svgeditor-as3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess from this bug that it's not currently possible:

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-605

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, but you could try to convert to a bitmap and then vectorize the bitmap (something like the [marching squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) algorithm)

If you are drawing it in AS, you could keep track of your drawing, possibly by extending Graphics & Sprite or Shape to use the new class.